# .htaccess redirect AMP from middle of URL to the end?

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, amp-html

how can I by using rewritecond redirect all AMP urls like this (for all articles):
domain.com/amp/some-article-url/ => domain.com/some-article-url/amp/
I have this code that doing opposite and I don't know how to reverse:

```
#RewriteEngine On
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/amp(.*)$
#RewriteRule ^ /amp/%1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*/)?amp/(?!page/\d+)([^?\s]+?)/?[?\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1%2/amp/ [R=301,L,NE]
```

Better to use `THE_REQUEST` instead of `REQUEST_URI` as `REQUEST_URI` may change due to execution of other rules.

Comment: Doesn't work, nothing happening with URL. I also tested here https://www.neting.it/multiple-urls-htaccess-redirect-checker.php

Comment: Ok, sorry, my mistake. I put now on top and it works. Thanks!

Comment: I have problem with paginating homepage. How can I exclude these URLs from your condition: domain.com/amp/page/X (X can be any number)? So, htaccess rule no need to rewrite AMP paginate links, only articles.

Comment: I tested and didn't worked. I removed space that you tell me. I tried also with some matching patterns (like (.*)) and no success. I think that code (!/page/\d+/?$) doesn't match domain.com/amp/page/X, it still making 301 to domain.com/page/X/amp

Comment: btw on my Apache, I tested above rule using `'localhost/amp/page/5'` and it didn't redirect so I suspect it is browser caching issue.

Comment: I tried different browsers, also checked with Facebook developers tools fetch link. This is URL example: https://www.example.com/amp/page/2/

Comment: Try updated rule as top rule. If it doesn't work then you will have to enable `RewriteLog` and check it's output as I cannot reproduce it.